# How to filter data based on one word of a column value?

Tags: r, filter, extract, rows

I have a dataframe that simplified looks like this only it has 2k rows. I'm wondering if there's a way to either extract data or filter data by the values in the LocationID column. I would like to extract rows that have the word "Creek" or "River" in them which would leave out the other names (such as the Banana Forest value).

```
 LocationID, Code
 Alk River, 232
 Bala River, 4324
 Banana Forest, 344
 Cake River, 432
 Alk Creek, 6767
 Cake Creek, 766
```

Thank you!

Comment: have a look at `?grep`

Comment: I'm new to R but I will look this up!

Comment: If you'd like to do this without installing packages, `grep` or `grepl` is more than adequate: `dat[grepl("river|creek", dat$LocationID, ignore.case=TRUE),]` for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
    filter(str_detect(LocationID, '\\b(River|Creek)\\b'))
#   LocationID Code
#1  Alk River  232
#2 Bala River 4324
#3 Cake River  432
#4  Alk Creek 6767
#5 Cake Creek  766
```

Comment: I got this error! Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : could not find function "str_detect" wait let me download tidyverse..

Comment: @JulietR  I should have mentioned `libraryr(tidyverse)`, It is in `library(stringr)`  updated the post

Comment: @JulietR  One option is to convert it to either upper or lower case and then get the unqiique rows.  Do you want to get the `sum` of 'Code' for those having different cases?